# What is this 0-1 combinatorial optimization called?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, terminology, discrete-optimization

Let’s say I have the following N polynomials:

$f_{1}(\boldsymbol{x}) = \Sigma_{i = 1}^{K} a_{1i} x_{i}$

$f_{2}(\boldsymbol{x}) = \Sigma_{i = 1}^{K} a_{2i} x_{i}$

...

$f_{N}(\boldsymbol{x}) = \Sigma_{i = 1}^{K} a_{Ni} x_{i}$

where $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_{1}, ..., x_{K})$ is a K-dimensional vector that takes either $0$ or $1$ as elements and $a_{ni}$ is an integer factor for each $x_{i}$ that can be a negative number.

I would like to create a vector $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_{1}, ..., x_{K})$ that makes $|f_{1}(\boldsymbol{x})|$ as large as possible while making $|f_{2}(\boldsymbol{x})|, \cdots, |f_{N}(\boldsymbol{x})|$ as small as possible.

What is this 0-1 combinatorial entity called and how do I solve this?

Comment: What does it mean to "minimize $f_2(x),\cdots f_N(x)$"? Is the comma a typo (so it would be the product)?

Comment: I meant “a vector x to maximize |f1| while making |f2|, |f3|, .., |fN| as small as possible.” I fixed the typo and modified some details.

Comment: It's not clear what that means. $|f_2|$ through $|f_N|$ will in general be minimized for different values of $x$.

Comment: Yes they will be. The problem has a main goal of making |f1| as large as possible. However, it has a constraint where you need to make |f2| through |fN| as small as possible at the same time with the same vector x.

Comment: @tatsuki.dev After receiving answers to your question, it is a good idea to respond or to accept the given answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One naive formulation which reduces to solving mixed-integer linear programs is:
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in \{0,1\}^K} \ |f_1(x)| \qquad \mbox{ subject to }  \quad  |f_i(x)|\le \epsilon, \quad 2\le \forall i\le N,
\end{equation}
for some small nonnegative number $\epsilon$. The ideal case for you happens at $\epsilon=0$.
The above formulation reduces to solving:
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in \{0,1\}^K, t\in \mathbb R} \ t \qquad \mbox{ subject to }  \quad f_1(x)\ge t\ge 0, \quad \mbox{ and } \quad |f_i(x)|\le \epsilon, \quad 2\le \forall i\le N,
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in \{0,1\}^K, t\in \mathbb R} \ t \qquad \mbox{ subject to }  \quad f_1(x)\le -t\le 0, \quad \mbox{ and } \quad |f_i(x)|\le \epsilon, \quad 2\le \forall i\le N.
\end{equation}

Thus, you need to start with $\epsilon =0$, and if any of the above formulations have an optimum, you are done. Otherwise, increase this parameter and the show must go on until any of the problems obtains a solution. Of course, finding the best $\epsilon$ is practically possible but maybe expensive because if one of the problems above has a solution for $\epsilon_1$, any of them might have a solution for a smaller $\epsilon_2$. One fast solver for the MILP is Gurobi!

Comment: I googled about Gurobi and it seemed nice. The actual problem I've been trying to solve has 100 binary variables and 10 constraints. I'm not sure if Gurobi solves this quickly but I will give it a try. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Sure, I think it works for that size. It has an industrial version that I've heard to be super-efficient.